# VBA Excel 2011: Worksheet.Move without having the sheet show itself

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to call `Worksheet.Move` without having the sheet's workbook come to the front?  I don't want the workbook to be visible on the screen and even turning off ScreenUpdating doesn't prevent this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply keep track of the active workbook before the move and reactivate after, like this

```
Sub Demo1()
    Dim wsToMove As Worksheet, wsBefore As Worksheet
    Dim wbActive As Workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wbActive = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsToMove = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") ' update to suit
    Set wsBefore = wsToMove.Parent.ActiveSheet ' update to suit
    wsToMove.Parent.Activate
    wsToMove.Move Before:=wsBefore
    wbActive.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm already doing something similar, but as I mentioned in the question, it doesn't prevent the workbook (wsToMove in your example) from showing.  Is there some way to do a Move without the workbook wanting to show itself?

Comment: Oops, instead of wsToMove I meant ThisWorkbook.

Comment: @skiaddict1 But it does restore the original wb to the front, and hides the activity with ScreenUpdating.  You can't _prevent_ the change because Activating the workbook is a "feature" of Sheet.Move

Comment: Yes I realise that the original workbook is restored.  However the activity is _not_ hidden, that's what I've been saying.  I _see_ the workbook that I don't want to see.  Thanks however for confirming that there's no way to prevent the workbook from being activated.  I'll avoid the use of Move.

Comment: Interesting, I tested this and for me the activity does not show (Excel 2010)

Comment: I'm on Excel 2011 (Mac).  I wish mine behaved like yours! :-)  Thanks again.

Comment: Just for kicks, I decided to see if hiding the workbook would help matters.  It doesn't: Move pukes :-(